# How to put values into array structs?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to make account system in C.
I'm trying this way to make input to struct arrays.

```
struct account {                  // Account Structure
int id;
int money;
char *name[30];
};
account * accountarray[50];
int number;


void MakeAccount() {
int id;
int input_money;
char name[50];

printf("--Make Account--\n");
printf("Input ID : ");
scanf("%d", &id);
printf("Insert Money : ");
scanf("%d", &input_money);
printf("Your Name? : ");
scanf("%s", name);

accountarray[number++] = NULL;                // I think there's a problem in this side
accountarray[number++]->id = id;
accountarray[number++]->money = input_money;
*accountarray[number++]->name = name;
}
```

It stops when i get input the values... I think 4 codes on under has problem..
is there a good way to make it better?

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Study pointers and arrays more. You have a struct `account` type with an array of thirty pointer-to-char (not an array of char, an array of pointer-to-char) as a member, and a global array of fifty pointer-to `account`. In all of this only one thing actually has any of those pointers *pointing* to something, and it's a temporary (`name`). You repeated increment of `number` between each field assignment looks *terribly* wrong as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, Thanks. I think i didn't need pointer in this section. Solved to put values and checked it is ok. Saw other guy used pointer for this, Tried that way and didn't work. I think i really need to study more pointers lol

Comment: Indeed, WhozCraig is right. `accountarray[number++] = NULL; ` followed by `accountarray[number++]->id = id;`... This mistake (null pointer dereference) should be obvious *if* you're reading a book. Are you reading a book?

Comment: @Seb No i've been doing by myself. I just misunderstood about using pointer to structure

Comment: You can't learn C safely by unguided trial and error; you need a guide (e.g. a book), or you risk relying upon non-portable undefined behaviour such as this. The problem with undefined behaviour is it isn't always guaranteed to produce a crash; in fact, you're lucky in this case as the very definition of *undefined behaviour* means *there are no guarantees*. Many problems with undefined behaviour are **extremely difficult** to debug, such as race conditions, buffer overflows, sequence point abuse... and *these* can also cause security issues. **Stop guessing and start reading!**

Comment: I can recommend K&R2E. When you come across an exercise, do the exercise before you move on. If you have problems with the exercise, come and ask a question about it here.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier, that is one less than the length of the input buffer, to avoid the user input overflowing the buffer.  Such overflow is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: Thanks for all comment! It helped well :D

Comment: regarding this line: `account * accountarray[50];`  The result is an array of 50 pointers, NOT an array of 50 instances of the struct. And this line will not compile.   Suggest: `struct account accountarray[50];`  << notice no `*` and the addition of the `struct` modifier.

Comment: regarding this field: `char *name[30];` This declares an array of 30 `pointers to char` What you really want is an array of 30 characters: `char name[30];`.  << notice no `*`.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 30, 50  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest  using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this line: `*accountarray[number++]->name = name;`  Strings can not be copied via an assignment statement.  That ONLY copies a pointer to the string.  Suggest using `strcpy( accountarray[number].name, name );`  Note: giving only an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array

Comment: Did you know that `x++` modifies `x`? If you do `int x = 1; x++;`, then `x` is two after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably don't need pointers here because you made a assumption about max size of name as 30 and 50 accounts. So here is the modifications that I think you could make:

```
 struct account {                  // Account Structure
   int id;
   int money;
   char name[30];  // an array of characters
 };
 struct account accountarray[50]; // Note: its type is "struct account"
 int number;

 void MakeAccount() {
  int id;
  int input_money;
  char name[30];

  printf("--Make Account--\n");
  printf("Input ID : ");
  scanf("%d", &id);
  printf("Insert Money : ");
  scanf("%d", &input_money);
  printf("Your Name? : ");
  scanf("%s", name);

  accountarray[number++].id = id;
  accountarray[number++].money = input_money;
  memcpy(accountarray[number++].name, name, strlen(name)); // Note I used memcpy to copy one array of characters into another
}
```

Comment: actually not a good answer, the returned value from `scanf()` not being checked, the call to `scanf()` for `name` allows the user to overrun the input field, which would result in undefined behavior,  missing all the needed `#include` statements for `printf()`, `scanf()`, `strlen()`, `memcpy()` Uses 'magic' numbers.

Comment: @user3629249 :-) you missed  a few: not defining a macro for `30`. Not defining a macro for `50`. And probably I should use `unsigned` for the `id` and `money`. Definitely an `unsigned` for  `number`. And more importantly `void MakeAccount(void)` is the correct way to define a function without parameter... But here is a small thing to think about: OP is trying to learn arrays and pointers. :-)

Comment: @Arash, I did mention the usage of 'magic' numbers (thats the 30 and 50)
Even though the OP is trying to learn arrays and pointers, I believe he should not ignore other items in the code.  Best to learn now, rather than develop bad habits that will be difficult to break later on.

Answer (score 1):

here is a version of your code.

1. it cleanly compiles
2. it is not executable as there is no `main()` function
3. it properly performs error checking
4. it properly outputs error messages to `stderr`
5. it properly declares the array of 'account' data
6. it makes appropriate use of blank lines  to group code blocks and activity blocks
7. it properly uses a string function to copy the `name` array
8. it exits the program when an error occurs
9. it is consistent in program indenting, for ease of readability
10. it give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names (and uses those meaningful names throughout the code
11. it avoids any possibility of overflowing the input buffers
12. it includes the necessary header files and comments why each header file is being included
13. it does not consume the final 'newline' sequence entered by the user, however, the call to `scanf()` for the `id` will consume that left over byte(s) in `stdin` as the "%d" input/conversion specifier when entering the next account, will consume leading `white space`

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf(), scanf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>   // strcpy()

// eliminate 'magic' numbers
#define MAX_STR_LEN 30
#define MAX_ACCTS   50

// define the struct
struct account
{                  // Account Structure
    int id;
    int money;
    char name[ MAX_STR_LEN ];
};

// prototypes
void MakeAccount( void );

// === file global data ===
// declare MAX_ACCTS instances of the struct
struct account accountarray[ MAX_ACCTS ];
// declare a counter
int number = 0;


void MakeAccount()
{
    int id;
    int input_money;
    char name[ MAX_STR_LEN ];

    int scanfStatus;

    printf("--Make Account--\n");

    printf("Input ID : ");
    scanfStatus = scanf("%d", &id);

    if( 1 != scanfStatus )
    { // then scanf failed
        // output error message, including the OS reason for the error to 'stderr'
        perror( "scanf for account id failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //implied else, scanf successful

    printf("Insert Money : ");
    scanfStatus = scanf("%d", &input_money);

    if( 1 != scanfStatus )
    { // then scanf failed
        // output error message, including the OS reason for the error to 'stderr'
        perror( "scanf for account money failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("Your Name? : ");
    scanfStatus = scanf("%29s", name); // note MAX CHARACTERS 1 less than length of input buffer

    if( 1 != scanfStatus )
    { // then scanf failed
        // output error message, including the OS reason for the error to 'stderr'
        perror( "scanf for account name failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    accountarray[number].id = id;
    accountarray[number].money = input_money;
    strcpy( accountarray[number].name, name);
} // end function: MakeAccount
```

Comment: awesome code, flawless learnt a lot. i should avoid using magic numbers

Answer (score 0):

i think you're trying to make more complex than it should have been, i did it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct account {                  // Account Structure
    int id;
    int money;
    char name[30];
};

int number;


int main() {
int id,x,input_money;
char name[50];
struct account accountarray[50];

printf("How many Number of accounts do you want to enter? ");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("--Make Account--\n");
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{

    printf("Input ID : ");
    scanf("%d", &accountarray[i].id);
    printf("Insert Money : ");
    scanf("%d", &accountarray[i].money);
    printf("Your Name? : ");
    scanf("%s", accountarray[i].name);
    printf("\n");
}
printf("****RECORD INSERTED****\n");
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    printf("\nID: %d",accountarray[i].id);
    printf("\nNAME: %s",accountarray[i].name);
    printf("\nMONEY: %d",accountarray[i].money);

}

}
```

you can check https://github.com/ashim888/csit-c for further information and code samples

Comment: That's another good way to solve. Thanks! I just changed `name` part using `strcpy`

Comment: I really love to.. sorry for my rep points. I'll do it when i get enough :D

Comment: @Gomtting no worries :)

Comment: regarding this line: `void main() {`  << not portable, will not cleanly compile, except under Visual Studio

Comment: Not a good answer, because: uses 'magic' numbers, does not separate code blocks, deviates from the logic and output given by the user, contains several unused variables, does not check that number of accounts desired by the user is <= the number of declared account space, does not check returned value from `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.  Does not follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: "only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement" isn't it that we can save some repetition of datatype when we declare same data type variable?